# Understanding black and white levels

Tags: image-editing, blender

Here's a simple image I took from pixabay, in a video about compositing, (I'm using blender's compositor here, but the general principle should apply), the author said, "**in this image, there's more tinge of yellow, so to get rid of more yellow , we increase the saturation (Hue was yellow-ish) of this white level**"

Which is basically increasing the amount of yellow: This is my example of how it was done, since I cannot include the author's original tut's image:

Before:
[image: Before]
After:
[image: after]
You can see that the yellow tone does come down.

But, I'm not quite understanding this principle and how does this analogy apply for the black level i.e. What if we set the RGB value for the Black level to be something yellow, how does it alter the image? (I mean I could see it in the compositor but I'd like to know the theory)

Comment: Do you know there is a [Blender stack exchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/). Probably better to ask there.

Comment: @BillyKerr, This like I said is more about the image and color. I mean, aren't black and white levels more about color and photography in general? I don't think this is tied to a particular software.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably confusing terms. Or the tutorial you are watching is.

- What is white balance
- What is the black point and white point?
- Saturation

In this case, if you choose a white balance on the wheat, the image desaturate it because it tries to make it a neutral color. That is the idea behind white balance.

Take a look at this post: https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/61493/color-issue-studio-images-have-a-pink-hue/61497#61497

Black and white points refer to the brightest and darkest points of your images, and not about its saturation.

Comment: But the term used is white level here, and not white point, they are the same?

Comment: No. You can have a white point not white, which in reality means neutral gray point. Take a look at the other post.